# What needs to be done to make an arbitrary model display in Blender Game Engine

Tags: modeling, game-engine

I've been trying to get some models to render in the blender game engine. I've picked up models on TurboSquid.com and BlenderSwap.com. The models render with F12 in the blender engine, but when I press `P` they appear to render nearly the same as the viewport when in texture mode.

This seems to be the case with most models I download and try to use in this way. Am I missing something I should do, or is it not reasonable to think I can download models designed for the renderer and think I can get them working in the game engine.

My end goal is simple: to pan a spotlight around the inside of a car interior using a few game engine logic bricks. I don't need the game engine version to look as good as a full rendering, but I'd like to use one of these pre-built models and see the spotlight move around.

Comment: "*or is it not reasonable to think I can download models designed for the renderer and think I can get them working in the game engine*" You generally cannot. Materials need to be made specifically for the Game Engine/Blender Internal

Comment: I did make sure to choose models that render properly in the Blender Internal Engine. But there is still a substantial difference between rendering and `P`laying a game.